# ruby/js, how do i create a page with placeholders with mobile tags?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, web, dynamic-data

The tags (just a box with words) can be dragged into the placeholders and links to other pages upon clicking the tags.

There should also be an option to create new placeholder columns or rows for more variety.